# Which is the Best Scan and Diagnostic tool for Asian Vehicles?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, suzuki, kia, scan-tool

I am looking for a Scanner and Diagnostic tool that will be used for Asian Vehicles. I am not sure which scanner to buy which works with Asian makes like Toyota, Hyundai, Kia, Mahendra, Suzuki and more

Comment: You'll probably have better luck checking forums for the Japanese makes in question. Product advice is out of the scope of this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As long as we are talking about US spec "Asian" vehicles, my personal preference is one of the many "Autel" brand scan tools, which *for me* have always been able to link up and give good results.

I have a 1997 Subaru which the Autel works well on.  Keep in mind this vehicle uses a rare protocol, and is only one year past the 1996 US cutoff which mandated OBD II compatibility,  This tool has never failed me.  While I own a very expensive SnapOn Solus scan tool with Asian, Domestic, and Euro software (a plus $8k investment over the years) the Autel tool is the one I grab and doesn't fail me for *generic* as well as *make-specific* P codes on all vehicles.  It also does other codes, SRS, ABS brakes, and has live graphs and sensor readings as well (Autel 301).

It also has a "Monitor Ready" mode that fits on one screen and is ideal for trying to complete a drive cycle before the dreaded "P0420" Catalytic Converter Efficiency shows up preventing a successful emissions inspection.

I'm sure there are other effective scan tools, and I have no personal financial relationship with Autel.

However, in terms of "bang for buck" I have found no better.  Asian, Euro, Domestic.

If you are speaking of Asian vehicles used in Asia, I have no advice whatsoever, as they may or may not conform to OBD II regulations.

Comment: How's eobd2 for subarus on the autel? snapon scanners are horrible for anything earlier than 2010 and i stick to global obd2 when working n subarus most of the time.

Comment: @Ben  better than most, I'd say.  My Solus pro has been fine on my '97 Outback Sport and '05 Saab 92x, but so has the Autel.  There's not much beyond generic OBD II on a '97 Subaru anyway...  The bluetooth ones I've tried won't link up at all.